# Taking a list of enums with multiple attributes and putting them into an ArrayList or HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, enums, hashmap, hashtable

I have an Enum class of People, with each person enum being defined as:

```
enumName(String name, String age, String Occupation)
```

Example:

```
public enum People{
    Joe1("Joe","31","Engineer"),
    Joe2("Joe","35","Manager"),
    Sam1("Sam", "22", "Student"),
    Sam1("Sam", "22", "Student"),
    Sam1("Sam", "23", "Student"),
    Sam2("Sam", "30", "lawyer"),
    Sam3("Sam", "45", "judge");
}
```

It's Joe1 and Joe2 represent data for the same person, Joe but for a different age/occupation. How can I make an ArrayList or Hashmap/table of the names along with the different ages/occupations that can be searched for by the name of the person?

So i'm not sure how the data structure would look like or even if it is the correct one but I want to be able to search for a name and get every age and occupation values associated with that name, so for example I would search "Joe" and get this returned:

```
Joe-31-Engineer
Joe-35-Manager
```

For Sam's values, there are duplicates but I still want to be able to see them when I search up Sam's name "Sam":

```
 Sam-22-Student
 Sam-22-Student
 Sam-23-Student
 Sam-30-lawyer
 Sam-45-judge
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a static variable inside the enum which is initialized with people group by the `personName` :

```
enum People {
    Joe1("Joe", "31", "Engineer"), 
    Joe2("Joe", "35", "Manager"), 
    Sam1("Sam", "22", "Student"),
    Sam2("Sam", "30", "lawyer"), 
    Sam3("Sam", "45", "judge");

    private String personName;
    private String age;
    private String occupations;

    private static Map<String, List<People>> byName;

    static {
        byName = Arrays.stream(values())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(People::getPersonName, 
                          Collectors.toList()));
    }

    People(String personName, String age, String occupations) {
        this.personName = personName;
        this.age = age;
        this.occupations = occupations;
    }
    public static List<People> getByName(String personName) {
             return byName.get(personName);
    }
}
```

Then you can search people(ages,occupations) by name with the following declaration :

```
 List<People> p = People.getByName("Joe");
```

Comment: What is the 'Static {...} portion of your code doing? Are you making a new method or operating on the object?

Comment: The purpose of static block here is only to initialize the static variable. I think it is the best way to initialize the `byName` variable when the enum load.

Comment: Ah I see, let me try it out

Comment: List<People> p= byName.get("personName") just returns null though or should p be iterated through to have proper printed output?

Comment: Please see the response, I did some modification. Now you can get use the getByName method.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using the .stream() method to print out all the values. I really appreciate it. Out of curiosity/side note, if you wanted to search for names by their age, what functionality would you add to cut down on the results?

Comment: May be `stream().filter()` should be suitable for this search.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `Map<String, List<People>>`. For each name, you'll have a corresponding value that is the list of `enum` values with that name. You also cannot have more than one value of an enum with the same name, so there can only be one `Sam1`.